# Getting the URLs of image posts on Reddit

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm working on a reddit bot that's purpose is to find reposts when it detects a comment containing "!repostfinder". The bot is able to detect the string, but I don't know how to get the image that was commented on.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
#subreddit to use
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('test')

#summoning the bot
keyphrase = '!repostfinder'

#find comments with keyphrase
for comment in subreddit.stream.comments():
    if keyphrase in comment.body:
        print('Found keyphrase')
        comment.reply('Keyphrase detected')
        print('Replied to comment')
```

Answer (score 1):

**You should read the relevant docs of the `praw` library that you are using.**

Here are the docs of `praw.models.reddit.comment.Comment`: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/comment.html?highlight=comment

You can get the comment's submission by using `comment.submission`. Then it is up to you what to do with the data.
Here are the docs of `praw.models.reddit.submission.Submission`: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html?highlight=submission

Example:

```
# Fetch some comments
comments = []
for comment in subreddit.stream.comments():
    # Stop after fetching some comments
    if (len(comments) < 10):
        comments.append(comment)
    else:
        break
# Select specific comment
comment = comments[0]
# Get the comment's submission
submission = comment.submission
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `parent_id` value for every comment. In case its a top comment the parrent id will start with a `t3_` (its a post, you gotta check that) while if the parent id is another comment it will start with `t1_` which means it was a reply to another comment, which in your case would be useless information.

So now u do:

```
postData = reddit(id=subbmission.parrent_id[3:]) # This is how u get the post object
print(postData.url) # The URL of the image
```